# CollectionViewController logic error?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to implement a Collection View Controller. However, for some random reason every time I run the iOS simulator the images do not appear... Also, the compiler does not throw me any error... So, I do not know what I am missing here...

**CollectionView Controller**

```
import UIKit

let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

     var imagesCell : [String] = []

     @IBOutlet var collectionSaso: UICollectionView!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    // Register cell classes
    self.collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    imagesCell = ["miEsposa.jpg", "miEsposa.jpg", "miEsposa.jpg"]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of sections
    return 0
}


override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //#warning Incomplete method implementation -- Return the number of items in the section
    return imagesCell.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionSaso.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CollectionViewCell

    // Configure the cell
    cell.imageHolder.image = UIImage(named: imagesCell[indexPath.item])
    return cell
}
```

**CollectionViewCell**

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageHolder: UIImageView!
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you not see the warning that Apple has provided in the numberOfSectionsInCollectionView method? You shouldn't ignore warnings.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return 1 for number of sections.